# Can't run my JavaScript code directly on system

Tags: javascript, syntax

I am unable to run this javascript code in the terminal even though the code is correct! I am using visual studio. and it runs perfectly when I click on run code but doesn't run in terminal

[image: error snap]

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute your JavaScript that way because your computer does not know how to.

(Computer) code can only get executed in a certain environment. E. g. Java needs the JRE (Java Runtime Environment), and JavaScript needs its own environment, too.

---

One environment would be your webbrowser (what JavaScript was initially designed for).

So if I execute JavaScript here in the webbrowser, it works!
Why? Because it has a JavaScript engine (the environment JavaScript needs to be executed in) already built in.

```js
const sayHello = name => {
  return "hey there " + name + "!";
};

console.log(sayHello("John"));
```

---

If you want to execute JavaScript directly on your system like you tried, you will need to install such an evironment like your browser already has. [Node.js](https://nodejs.org) would be such an option.

After you have installed it on your system, you can run `node your-file.js` and you will see your expected output on the console.